# LibGdx Power Of Two Texture Size For Texture Atlas Only?

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es, libgdx

I was reading about POT of textures and their benefits, was curious , let's say I put many non-POT textures into a texture atlas (basically a single texture) whose size is a power of two, do I still get the benefits?

Comment: Yes, texture regions in an atlas are only a way to pass specific UVs to the SpriteBatch.